# How does one map a drive on a Windows 10 device managed by Intune?

Tags: azure, windows-10, entra-id, microsoft-intune

I'm trying to setup some basic group policy settings with Microsoft Intune. We have Windows 10 Enterprise installed on all our devices and they are Azure AD joined. To start I wanted to map a network share to one of the devices, but I can't find options to do so. You can create custom OMA-URI settings, but I have no idea how to set this up to map a fileshare.

I managed to setup conditional access and enfore Bitlocker encryption, but those settings are available by default. Does anyone have experience working with the custom settings? I can't find anything good in the Intune documentation, so maybe it's just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a powershell script to map a network drive pretty easily.

Here is a link to a list of all available CSP's for windows 10:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/configuration-service-provider-reference

Comment: I wouldn't use a powershell script at logon, way too slow and huge footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, Group Policies were only registry settings. The drive mapping functionality that you are trying to replicate is handled by a newer extension to Group Policy known as [Group Policy Preferences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848751.aspx). From what I can tell, at this moment, [Custom Configuration Service Provider settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/create-a-custom-configuration-service-provider) can only tweak registry settings and WMI values.

I did see that it was possible to push Edge Favorites and Start Menu Charms. You could try pushing them with UNC paths.

I also stumbled onto a [drive mapping Powershell script](https://gitlab.com/Lieben/assortedFunctions/blob/master/intuneServerShareMapper.ps1), which is designed to be assigned through Intune, that might work for you. Or, at least, be a good place to start.